# D2RQ default mapping scheme

Tags: database, rdf, jena, sesame, d2rq

What is the default mapping scheme for D2RQ? 
Is it triple-based mapping, value-based mapping or object-based mapping?

Answer (score 1):

[The documentation](http://d2rq.org/getting-started) says:

> The [`generate-mapping` script](http://d2rq.org/generate-mapping) automatically generates a D2RQ mapping
>   from the table structure of a database. The tool generates a new RDF
>   vocabulary for each database, using table names as class names and
>   column names as property names. Semantic Web client applications will
>   understand more of your data if you customize the mapping and replace
>   the auto-generated terms with terms from well-known and publicly
>   accessible RDF vocabularies.
>
> The mapping file can be edited with any text editor. Its syntax is
>   described in the D2RQ language specification.

The [DR2 Server Tutorial](http://sw.cs.technion.ac.il/d2rq/tutorial) gives a bit more detail, although it uses a [non-default mapping file](http://sw.cs.technion.ac.il/d2rq/tutorial_files/mapping-iswc.ttl).  You might begin by working through the tutorial, examining the mapping generated by the script, and then comparing it to the one provided for the tutorial.